# Restricting usage of keywords in Common Lisp (SBCL)

Tags: common-lisp, keyword, read-eval-print-loop, sbcl, restriction

Using SBCL's implementation of Common Lisp, is it somehow possible to present a REPL where usage of specific keywords is prohibited (effectively providing access to only a subset of Common Lisp's functionality)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defpackage :limited-repl
  (:use :cl :named-readtables)
  (:export #:within-sandbox
           #:limited-repl))

(in-package :limited-repl)
```

In this answer I define a `within-sandbox` macro and a `limited-repl` function, such that:

1. the current package is a fresh package that exists only during the execution of the sandbox, to avoid polluting a single package with a lot of different symbols entered by the user
2. only an allowed list of symbols are visible to the user
3. special characters like `#\:` and `#\#` are forbidden, to prevent the user from accessing symbols in other packages, and to avoid using syntax that might create arrays, bitvectors, etc. as well as reader variables (`#1=` and `#1#`), which could be used to create circular structures that loops infinitely when evaluated.
4. the empty list is not equivalent to `COMMON-LISP:NIL`, in order to avoid introducing this symbol in the custom language; instead, it reads as zero.

#### readtable

I am using the `named-readtables` library, which is available in Quicklisp, in order to define a custom readtable. This can be achieved with Common Lisp too if necessary.

```
(ql:quickload :named-readtables)
```

Let's define a custom condition for forbidden-characters, this is a bit cleaner than using `(error "some string")`:

```
(define-condition forbidden-character (error)
  ((character :initarg :character :reader forbidden-character.character)
   (stream :initarg :stream :reader forbidden-character.stream))
  (:report (lambda (condition stream)
             (format stream
                     "Forbidden character ~@c"
                     (forbidden-character.character condition)))))
```

Let's also define a reader function that signals an error for the character being read:

```
(defun forbidden-character (stream character)
  (error 'forbidden-character
         :character character
         :stream stream))
```

Here is the list reader that returns zero on an empty list:

```
(defun read-zero-list (stream character)
  (assert (char= character #\())
  (let ((list (read-delimited-list #\) stream t)))
    (etypecase list
      (null 0)
      (cons list))))
```

The `limited-repl` readtable is based on the standard readtable, except for two forbidden characters and a custom list reader:

```
(defreadtable limited-repl
  (:merge :standard)
  (:macro-char #\( 'read-read-zero-list)
  (:macro-char #\: 'forbidden-character nil)
  (:macro-char #\# 'forbidden-character nil))
```

#### language package

The `limited-language` package defines the base language the user can access, here only basic arithmetic symbols and the `quit` symbol:

```
(defpackage limited-language
  (:use)
  (:export #:+
           #:-
           #:*
           #:/
           #:quit))
```

I also redefine the functions as wrapper around the CL functions, as follows:

```
(macrolet ((lift (s c) `(defun ,s (&rest args) (apply #',c args))))
  (lift limited-language:- cl:-)
  (lift limited-language:+ cl:+)
  (lift limited-language:* cl:*)
  (lift limited-language:/ cl:/))
```

This is necessary because just reexporting the CL symbols could have unintended effects, like for example the user accessing the variables `*` or `/` which are bound in Lisp, which we do not want here.

#### temporary packages

The following auxiliary function calls `function` in a context where `*package*` is bound to a fresh, temporary package that uses `limited-language`. I am using [`GENTEMP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gentem.htm) to generate a fresh symbol in a `package-names` package:

```
(defpackage package-names
  (:use))

(defun call-with-temporary-package (function)
  (let* ((symbol (gentemp "SANDBOX-" 'package-names))
         (package (make-package symbol :use '(limited-language))))
    (unwind-protect (let ((*package* package))
                      (funcall function))
      (delete-package package)
      (unintern symbol 'package-names))))
```

When no REPL is running, `package-names` is empty, as the generated symbols are uninterned on unwinding. The temporary package is also deleted. There might be a more robust way to define temporary names for packages, this should be enough as a first draft.

#### sandbox environment

The `within-sandbox` macro establishes the context where the readtable and the package is set to the ones we want. I also bind `*read-eval*` to nil, just to be sure no code is evaluated while `read` is performed:

```
(defmacro within-sandbox (&rest body)
  `(call-with-temporary-package
    (lambda ()
      (let ((*readtable* (find-readtable 'limited-repl))
            (*read-eval* nil))
        ,@body))))
```

#### simple limited REPL

Finally, the REPL is defined as follows, where `quit` is used to quit the REPL:

```
(defun limited-repl ()
  (within-sandbox
   (loop
     (format t "~&> ")
     (finish-output)
     (clear-input)
     (handler-case (let ((form (read)))
                     (when (eq form 'limited-language:quit)
                       (return))
                     (eval form))
       (cl:end-of-file ()
         (return))
       (:no-error (v)
         (print v))
       (error (e)
         (format *error-output* "~&Error: ~a~%" e))))))
```

#### example

```
CL-USER> (limited-repl:limited-repl)

> 5

5 
> (+ () (* 4 3) (/ 7 9))

115/9 
> #1=(list 0 . #1#)

Error: Forbidden character #\#
> *

Error: The variable * is unbound.
> (cl:in-package 'cl-user)

Error: Forbidden character #\:
> quit
NIL
CL-USER>
```

#### conclusion

When limiting the symbols the user can access, you can rely on `eval`. However, this can still introduce CL specific semantics in your language, like when writing `*` alone reports an undefined variable `*` (maybe your language has no variable concept). You would then need to write your own `evaluate` function, which can delegate to `eval`, but which can also do other things outside of Common Lisp.
There might be some other things I failed to consider for the sandboxed environment (execution times, etc.), be careful, but that should be already useful as-is.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [`defpackage`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpkg.htm) macro.

If you want to prohibit only some functions, you will use `:shadow` keyword:

```
(defpackage "MY-PACKAGE"
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:shadow :list :cons))
```

If you want to prohibit everything and allow only some functions, you will use `:import-from` keyword:

```
(defpackage "ONLY-MATH"
  (:use)
  (:import-from :common-lisp  :+ :- :* :/ :print))
```

Then call `(in-package "MY-PACKAGE")` or `(in-package "ONLY-MATH")` in REPL and try some examples:

```
ONLY-MATH 2 > (+ 1 2)
3

ONLY-MATH 3 > (cons 1 2)

Error: Undefined operator CONS in form (CONS 1 2).
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can import only specific symbols, this does not *prohibit* their use, as you can explicitly refer to them using the package prefix.

If you want to expose a REPL to the user that they cannot abuse to manipulate your system, you will have to safely read their input and explicitly create the evaluation rules.